# C# Listbox Filter with Linq fulltext search query

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, search, listbox

I have the following problem. I have a `WPF` Listbox which is bound to an `ObservableCollection`. Now I want to filter the items in the box with a full text string.

I do it by running a linq query on the `ObservableCollection` and binding the list to the result of the query. It works generally but there are some behaviors I can't explain.

**Example entries of the list:**
CMSRC_XXX_ADDR, CMDST_XXX_ADDR, TXDAT_DMA_ST_ADDR, ...

**Search queries that work:**
*ADDR, XXX, XX, ADD, CM*

**Search queries that do NOT work:**
*CMS, CMSR,...*

When I type `CM` it still shows the the `CMSRC_XXX_ADDR` entry. When I enter `CMS` the `CMSRC_XXX_ADDR` is not shown anymore.

Does anybody know why? I hope my question is clear. Thanks for the help.

Regards
Dominik

```
        string txtOrig = text;
        string lower = txtOrig.ToLower();
        string normalize = txtOrig.Normalize();

        var bitfieldsfiltered = from bit in bitfields
                                let name = bit.name_
                                where
                                name.ToLower().StartsWith(lower)
                                || name.StartsWith(txtOrig)
                                || name.Normalize().StartsWith(normalize)
                                || name.ToLower().Contains(lower)
                                || name.Contains(txtOrig)
                                || name.Normalize().Contains(normalize)
                                || name.ToLower().EndsWith(lower)
                                || name.EndsWith(txtOrig)
                                || name.Normalize().EndsWith(normalize)
                                || name.ToLower().Equals(lower)
                                || name.Equals(txtOrig)
                                || name.Normalize().Equals(normalize)
                                select bit;
         list_box.ItemsSource = bitfields;
```

**UPDATE:** Error does not exist. The Data in the Labels were not the data in the listbox. There was the underscore missing because of RecognizesAccessKey.

Comment: Wow!  Why are you not using one of the StringComparison enums?  It can simplify your logic by about 66% and make it easier to debug.  Just curious?

Comment: @GarryVass because he may not know about such an enum.

Comment: @user2591237, if you rescope your question to include that you are happy to accept logic/efficiency improvements?

Comment: @GarryVass yes i would accept every improvment. I don't need it to do that way. It just needs to work. Regards

Comment: I will upload some code that reduces the complexity of your query and make it easier to implement diagnostics to be sure that your query is performing the way you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things that can be done to fix this behaviour.  To start, go to your solution and "Add" -> "New Project" -> "Test" -> "Unit Test Project".  This is Vs2012, and in Vs2010 the menus will be slightly different.

Once the test project initializes, do "Add" -> "New Item" -> "Class".  Then paste the following code into that class...

```
[TestClass]
public class MyQueryUnitTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        BitQuery bitQuery = new BitQuery();
        var result = bitQuery.Query("ADDR");
        Assert.IsTrue(result.Count==3);
    }
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod2()
    {
        BitQuery bitQuery = new BitQuery();
        var result = bitQuery.Query("XXX");
        Assert.IsTrue(result.Count == 2);
    }
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod3()
    {
        BitQuery bitQuery = new BitQuery();
        var result = bitQuery.Query("CMS");
        Assert.IsTrue(result.Count==1);
    }
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod4()
    {
        BitQuery bitQuery = new BitQuery();
        var result = bitQuery.Query("CMSR");
        Assert.IsTrue(result.Count == 1);
    }
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod5()
    {
        BitQuery bitQuery = new BitQuery();
        var result = bitQuery.Query("CM");
        Assert.IsTrue(result.Count == 2);
    }
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod6()
    {
        BitQuery bitQuery = new BitQuery();
        var result = bitQuery.Query("DUMMY");
        Assert.IsTrue(result.Count == 2);
    }
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod7()
    {
        BitQuery bitQuery = new BitQuery();
        var result = bitQuery.Query("");
        Assert.IsTrue(result.Count == 5);
    }
}
public class BitQuery
{
    public ObservableCollection<bit> bitfields = new ObservableCollection<bit>();
    public BitQuery()
    {
        bitfields.Add(new bit { name_ = "CMSRC_XXX_ADDR" });
        bitfields.Add(new bit { name_ = "CMDST_XXX_ADDR" });
        bitfields.Add(new bit { name_ = "TXDAT_DMA_ST_ADDR" });
        bitfields.Add(new bit { name_ = "WWWW_DUMMY" });
        bitfields.Add(new bit { name_ = "ABCDE_DUMMY" });
    }
    public List<bit> Query (string text)
    {
        string txtOrig = text;
        string lower = txtOrig.ToLower();
        string normalize = txtOrig.Normalize();
        var bitfieldsfiltered = from bit in bitfields
                                let name = bit.name_
                                where IsMatch(txtOrig, name)
                                select bit;
        return bitfieldsfiltered.ToList();
    }
    private bool IsMatch(string txtOrig, string name)
    {
        if (name.StartsWith(txtOrig, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) return true;
        if (name.IndexOf(txtOrig, 0, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0) return true;
        return false;
    }
}
public class bit
{
    public string name_ { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return name_;
    }
}
```

And then tell Visual Studio to run the unit tests.  VS will open a window that lights up in various colours and run the tests.

All of the tests show that the problem you have described has been fixed and you are getting back the expected results!

Of immediate interest is the replacement of your lengthy "OR" clauses with the simple method...

```
    private bool IsMatch(string txtOrig, string name)
    {
        if (name.StartsWith(txtOrig, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) return true;
        if (name.IndexOf(txtOrig, 0, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0) return true;
        return false;
    }
```

---which does essentially the same thing.  NOTE:  you will need to add some more unit tests to cover all the various conditions.  Once you have a very high level of confidence that your query is robust and unfailingly accurate, you can plug it back in to your listbox.

The other change worth taking on board is this line...

```
return bitfieldsfiltered.ToList();
```

This takes the LINQ result and 'locks it down'.  In your original code you left it as an unevaluated query (which may or may not affect this specific case, but it's always a good idea to lock it down if you are presenting something on the user surface).

So your "CMS" and "CMSR" queries are working now, and you have some unit tests where you can introduce additional conditions and be confident the whole thing works.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I would like to vote up, but i don't have 15 reputations yet.

Comment: You don't need rep to place an "Accept" on the answer (i.e., the checkmark under the vote display).  Doing so will signal that you're happy with the answer, and will also keep me alert for any future questions you post.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is very inefficient and you are checking the same thing multiple times. You can just call

```
name.ToLower().Contains(lower)
```

instead of

```
name.ToLower().Contains(lower)
```

and

```
name.ToLower().StartsWith(lower)
```

and

```
name.ToLower().Equals(lower)
```

and

```
name.ToLower().EndsWith(lower)
```

Try replacing your whole `where` clause with this:

```
where name.ToLower().Contains(lower) || name.Normalize().Contains(normalize)
```

or maybe even this:

```
where name.ToLower().Contains(lower)
```

You should get better results then.

UPDATE >>>

When I need to filter a collection, I use an additional collection so that my original collection remains unchanged. It looks like you are filtering into the `bitfieldsfiltered` collection, but then using you `bitfields` collection as the `ListBox.ItemsSource` value... shouldn't you be displaying the `bitfieldsfiltered` collection?

Comment: Where does the bug he describes originate?  Or does this fix the bug?

Comment: @Sheridan Thanks a lot for your help. This is exactly the way i did it first. But this doesn't fix the bug and the same error occures again. This is why a added a lot of OR conditions.

Comment: @sheridan You are right! This was only an error in my example code. Not in my real code. But thanks a lot! I found the error. There were other data in the listbox than displayed because an underscore was not shown by a wpf label.

Comment: Glad you fixed your problem. Please add an answer to your question summarising your fix and then mark it as correct? Thanks.